# Bring DialogFragment to front of screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using DialogFragment. I want to show multi dialog. Here is my code:

```
void showDialog(Data[] listData) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(listData[i].getContent());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(newFragment, "dialog:"+i);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

So length of listData = 3. I will launch 3 dialog: A,B,C. Then the stack becomes:

```
| |
|C|
|B|
|A|
```

Now, dialog C will be front of screen, we can see dialog A and B (we can move dialog in screen). **So I want to touch on dialog B and bring dialog B to front of screen (Note: Don't hide/dismiss dialog A and C)**. And the stack expected:

```
| |
|B|
|C|
|A|
```

So how can I do that?
Thanks you!

Comment: As a guess, I would say a `replace` transaction on the fragment `B` should bring it forward on the screen and in the stack.